# Subtracting 2 fractions with variables in the denominator that have different exponents.

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

Sorry for the relatively elementary question, but I am having trouble remembering exactly how to do this type of problem. I am looking to simplify this:
$$
\frac{3}{4t^{1/4}} - \frac{1}{2t^{3/4}}
$$

and it needs to simplify to this:

$$
\frac{3\sqrt{t} - 2}{4 t^{3/4}}
$$

Thanks!

K

Comment: Looks good to me, you found the common denominator.

Comment: That's what wolfram spits out, but wolfram doesn't show how to get the common denominator. I used to do these problems all of the time but I haven't done this kind of math in a long long time. Just trying to remember HOW to find the common denominator with these types of problems.

Comment: You essentially multiplied each fraction by a 'special' form of 1. You multiplied the first fraction by $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}}$ and the second one by $\frac{2}{2}$, that changed nothing, but allowed you to get the same denominator, and then you were able to subtract the numerators over that 'common denominator.

Comment: Note: In general you want to take the least common multiple of the two denominators as the "common denominator", if you have trouble finding what that is (i.e., it isn't obvious), you can always default to taking the product of the two denominators as the common denominator.

Comment: Ahhh! That's its! Would you like to post "answer this question" so I can give you the checkmark for the answer? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general to find the common denominator of two fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ take the $lcm(b,d)$. If that step is computationally cumbersome, then you can always take $bd$ as a common denominator.

That is to say, $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{3}{4t^{1/4}}-\frac{1}{2t^{3/4}} &=& 
\frac{3}{4t^{1/4}}\frac{t^{2/4}}{t^{2/4}} -\frac{1}{2t^{3/4}}\frac{2}{2} \\
&=&\frac{3 t^{2/4}}{4t^{3/4}} - \frac{2}{4t^{3/4}} \\
&=&\frac{3 t^{1/2}-2}{4t^{3/4}} \\
&=&\frac{3 \sqrt{t}-2}{4t^{3/4}}
\end{eqnarray}

The point is that you make the denominators same and then you can simply add the numerators that turn up, and also that you use $x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$ and $x^{1/a}=\sqrt[a] x$ when dealing with exponentials.